# Do I need to re-select the previous pen into the DC, just before releasing it?

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I have the following dialog-box class:

```
class CInputDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CInputDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
    virtual ~CInputDlg();

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();

protected:
    afx_msg BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnCancel();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();

private:
    CPen m_Pen;
};
```

Here is the implementation of the callback routines:

```
BOOL CInputDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    m_Pen.CreatePen(...);
    return TRUE;
}

void CInputDlg::OnCancel()
{
    m_Pen.DeleteObject();
    CDialog::OnCancel();
}

void CInputDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    pDC->SelectObject(m_Pen);
    ...
    ReleaseDC(pDC);
}
```

As you can see, in the `OnPaint` routine, I do not re-select the previous pen into the DC.

I do this under the assumption that there is no need to, since I release the DC anyway.

Finally, in the `OnCancel` routine, I delete the pen (which is possibly selected in some DC).

Am I wrong in doing so, or is my assumption above correct?

MSDN isn't very clear about when I can or should delete objects.

I guess that this question is due to my poor understanding of DCs.

Thank you.

Comment: [*An application should always replace a new object with the original, default object after it has finished drawing with the new object.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That's a question you should be able to answer for yourself: Who owns the GDI resources (`SelectObject` does not transfer ownership)?

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks. The description in this link doesn't refer to the case of releasing the DC. That's what my question is about. Can you please refer to this scenario?

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't understand your comment. I create the pen, so that means I own it... right? Can I safely delete this object in the `OnCancel` routine, or is it possibly selected in some DC? Thanks.

Comment: `SelectObject` returns a graphics object as well. Who owns that? And what conclusions can you draw from that about restoring DC state prior to DC destruction?

Comment: @i: OK, I get it, but the basis for my misunderstanding (as also mentioned in the question) is - why do I need to restore the DC to its previous state prior to its destruction (well, prior to its release, to be more accurate)? Does it still exist somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: What you are doing is a direct violation of the MSDN guidance.  Trying to reason what might happen when you do it wrong is just not very productive.  Do it right and you don't have to figure it out and don't have to fear your program blowing up.  The wrong-ness started early btw, caching objects is sensible when they are expensive to create and cheap to store.  Drawing objects like a pen are the *exact* opposite, dirt-cheap to create and very expensive to store.  So fix that first, get rid of the m_Pen variable.  And now you can't help but write the code correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant: OK, thanks for clearing that up (in particularly, the "Drawing objects like a pen are dirt-cheap to create and very expensive to store" part).

Comment: why you again and again use not `CPaintDC dc(this)` which you and need for paint, but `CDC* pDC = GetDC();` ?

Comment: @RbMm: Because I am using it in order to draw into a child window (`CWnd` object) of the dialog-box.

Comment: Please keep in mind that you are simply getting a pointer to the device context and then you are drawing on it. What you are releasing is your pointer to the device context. The device context still exists. It is considered good program design to store the previous object at the time you select in a new object. And then, when you are done, select in the stored object. You leave the device context as you had started. Once you restored the original, you are then free to delete your own object, unless it came from one of the stock objects.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Thank you very much!!! Would `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC` do the job, or do I have to save and restore every object returned from `SelectObject`? (I have more than "just a pen" in my actual code).

Comment: @goodvibration - `I am using it in order to draw into a child window` - you need draw in child windows - when it receive `WM_PAINT` - already several time said. you select wrong place for draw

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, I know (and I regret for not mentioning it to you in my previous comment as I initially intended to). But the focus of my question here is about the "lifetime" of the DC, and what I can/should do before releasing it. So mentioning it once again isn't helping me out here much. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: every window receive it own `WM_PAINT` and you need draw at this event, but not when another window receive `WM_PAINT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an error to release a [device context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx) without restoring it to its initial state. At any given time a device context stores a reference to an object of 7 [graphics object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144962.aspx) types. Those objects are owned by the device context, and need to be cleaned up, when the device context is destroyed.

[SelectObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957.aspx)

> selects an object into the specified device context (DC). The new object **replaces** the previous object of the same type.

Not restoring a device context therefore leaves it with a reference to an object it does not own. When it comes time to tear it down, bad things happen<sup>1</sup>.

The rules are simple: Always restore a DC before passing it back to its owner (either the caller, or the system). If keeping tracking of each graphics object is too tedious or impracticable, you can use [SaveDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162945.aspx) on entry and [RestoreDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162929.aspx) on exit.

Bonus reading:

- [What are the dire consequences of not selecting objects out of my DC?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130306-00/?p=5043)

---

<sup>1</sup> *In theory anyway. Because there is so much bad code out there, the system has implemented a fair bit of resilience against buggy GDI resource management.*

Comment: Note also that this specific question is about `ReleaseDC`, which does not delete the DC. It just returns the DC to a cache. So your cache now has a dirty object, which not only means leakage, but also means that when you ask for another DC, you might get a dirty one.